# Swiper Slide, как вывести пагинацию в виде цифр?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, slider

Подскажите, как выводить свою пагинацию в слайдере swiper вида 1 2 3 и т д

Comment: [Custom Pagination](https://swiperjs.com/demos/#custom_pagination)

Answer (score 0):

```
pagination: {
  el: '.swiper-pagination',
  type: 'fraction',
},
```